# Diagnosing memory leak in Appcelerator titanium iOS iPad app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on an iPad App that is built with Appcelerator Titanium Studio.

The app works great in simulator, but it crashes every now and then in the older models of iPad. So, I decided to see what's happening with the app by letting it run in simulator and using the `XCode Instruments` to see any leak.

As expected, there appears to be some leaks, this is what I can see in the report:

[image]

I have no idea what this thing is reporting back. How do you use this report to find the leak in your app? Has anyone got any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

memory leaks is all up to your code. There are no specific memory leaks you can just point to. However, there is a pretty good blogpost with some great basic rules you will have to follow to prevent memory leaks.

In case there are any memory leaks in Appcelerator's code, you will need to report it to their [JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.com). However, my app for example is pretty big and I haven't encountered any so far. And if there are, they are tiny, as the memory usage is pretty consistent.

http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate the memory leak, try "Allocation" instrument.

You can follow [this article](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Memory_and_Finding_Leaks).